# Laplace Transform: Basis

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

I tend to think of the Fourier Transform (FT) as projecting a function onto a basis of cosines and sines.  The Laplace Transform (LT) has a similar form to the FT, except it has been generalised.

Since the FT projects onto a basis of cosines and sines, cosines and sines turn up as dirac-deltas---this makes sense to me.  Now, I was wondering upon what basis the LT projects a function.  I figure that I could get a hint about what the basis upon which the LT projects, by looking at the ILT of a dirac delta.
$$
\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{\delta(\omega+a_0)\} \propto e^{j a_0 t}  \\
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\delta(s+a_0)\} =\ ?
$$
So the IFT of a dirac delta is making a purely complex exponential (makes sense) but I've no idea what the ILT would do.

Currently, I'm just viewing the LT as basically a FT, except that it multiples the function being transformed by some real exponential and then does a FT.

Could anyone perhaps shed some light on whether the LT is actually projecting onto a basis (like the FT is) and what that basis is?

Thanks.

Comment: I would think of the *inverse* Laplace transform as being projection onto the basis of exponentials $e^{-\alpha x}$, and the Laplace transform as expanding a function in this basis back to the delta basis. In the Fourier transform the two operations are equivalent since the Fourier basis is "orthonormal" in some sense, while the Laplace transform basis is *not* orthogonal.

Comment: The Laplace transform has no "basis" as such. There is only one exponential. Its more like the logarithms, there is no basis vectors for them.

Comment: @tpb261 can you elaborate more on "logarithms, there is no basis vectors for them."? Thanks.

Comment: @MilindR Laplace transforms a signal from one domain to another. Similarly the logarithm transforms the number from one domain to another. But neither of them can be considered a vector space.

Comment: @tpb261 Yes, but why not a vector space? The exponentials sound like they really could be the basis vectors... An infinite set.

Comment: sorry for the very delayed response. My understanding is this: In LT, the "s" is a parameter that can take various values. But by itself - the "s" doesn't define a Vector Space. And also, I doubt if there is an identity element in this case. I might be wrong (I hope I am).